# Can I set and access user preference from google assistant

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have an action that I created that I think will have a lot of value to a certain community.  The catch is that I access an API using a URL, and an APIKey.  It works great, however each user will have their own unique URL and APIKey.

Is there a way I can set up and use personalized setting for each user?  It would be best to put these values on their own google account, where the action can access these values, but I can not.

The only other option I can think if is simply sharing my code, to be customized, but I don't think google supports private assistants just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.  Here is how I did it.  Feedback is still welcome.

```js
const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;

function setKey(agent) {
  conv.user.storage.apiKey = parameters.APIKey;
  conv.ask('Ok, saving ' + parameters.APIKey);
  agent.add(conv);
}

function getKey(agent) {
  agent.add(`Your current key is ` + conv.user.storage.apiKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to store simple data for a user, you can use [user storage](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data) which persists a JSON object for a user.

```
function simpleResponse(conv) {
  conv.user.storage.count = 1;
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about ' +
      'almost any number, like 42. What do you have in mind?',
    text: 'Howdy! I can tell you fun facts about almost any ' +
      'number. What do you have in mind?',
  }));
}
```

If you are looking to use Firebase, as indicated in your tags, you can generate a unique ID for each user and save that ID into user storage. Afterwards, you can use that key as a way to look up the data in your database.

```
conv.user.storage.firebaseKey = '123';
firebase.database().ref('/data/123').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  let data = snapshot.val().myData;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick.  
I used that example exactly but when invoked I get the error.  
MalformedResponse'final_response' must be set.  
What seems to be working is this:    
    `function getDCAValue(agent) { . 
      console.log("Getting DCA Value");  
      //var responseText = . 
      return instance.get() . 
        .then(response => agent.add('Your DCA value is $' + (response.data.DCABalance * response.data.BTCUSDTPrice).toFixed(2)  )) . 
      .catch(error => agent.add('there was an error'));     
    }` . 

I’m not sure what the error is, is the the parameter of (agent) vs (conv) ?

Comment: Can I do something like this:   `function saveServer(agent) { agent.user.storage.server = agent.data.server;agent.add('Great! Saved it.');}`

Comment: It might be that you're using Dialogflow's fulfillment library instead of the Actions on Google fulfillment library.